# Xamarin, Grid не реагирует на изменение IsVisible забинженное методом

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, mvvm, xamarin

Есть CollectionView с mp3 файлами:

```
<CollectionView ... ItemsSource="{Binding MusicList}" SelectionMode="Single"
     SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedMusic}" SelectionChangedCommand="{Binding SelectionCommand}">
           ......
 </CollectionView>
```

Последнее свойство - забинженный SelectionChangedCommand отсылается на следующую команду:

```
public ICommand SelectionCommand => new Command(IsVisible);
```

Которая в свою очередь вызывает метод IsVisible:

```
public void IsVisible()
        {
            isVisible = true;
        }
```

Далее поле isVisible биндится к сетке:

`public bool isVisible;`

```
<Grid IsVisible="{Binding isVisible}">
               ...
</Grid>
```

Вопрос заключается в том почему разметка не меняется, хотя поле при отладке меняет значение. Какой должна быть правильная реализация этого? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: что такое `isVisible`? Поле? Свойство? INPC не забыли вызвать?

Comment: Поле, я писал выше

Comment: Я понял. Видимо дело в INPC. Просто первый раз узнал об этом, сейчас загуглил, буду думать над реализацией. Спасибо

Comment: 1) Биндинги на полях не раобтают, они работают только на свойствах 2) Изменение свойств подхватывается только если вы реализуете INPC и при изменении создаете соответвующее событие